# R lapply: check if data frame contains a column. If not, create this column

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes.

I would like to check every column name of the dataframes. If the column name is missing, I want to create this column to the dataframe, and complete with NA values.

Dummy data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=2:3, c=4:5)
d2 <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=2:3)

l<-list(d1, d2)

# Check the columns names of the dataframes 
# If column is missing, add new column, add NA as values 
lapply(l, function(x) if(!("c" %in% colnames(x))) 
             {
              c<-rep(NA, nrow(x))
              cbind(x, c) # does not work!
              })
```

**What I get:**

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
  a b  c
1 1 2 NA
2 2 3 NA
```

**What I want instead:**

```
[[1]]
  a b c
1 1 2 4
2 2 3 5

[[2]]
  a b c
1 1 2 NA
2 2 3 NA
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's what I would do: `lapply(l, function(x) {if(!"c" %in% names(x)) {x$c <- NA}; x})`. Check if c is in names, if no, create such a column with NAs. In both cases, return the data.frame.

Comment: @lmo, do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `dplyr::mutate` with an `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(l, function(x) mutate(x, c = ifelse("c" %in% names(x), c, NA)))

[[1]]
  a b c
1 1 2 4
2 2 3 4

[[2]]
  a b  c
1 1 2 NA
2 2 3 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some good answers, but if you want to stick to base R:

```
lapply(l, function(x) 
  if(!("c" %in% colnames(x))) {
  c<-rep(NA, nrow(x))
  return(cbind(x, c))
}
else(return(x))
)
```

Your code was returning `NULL` for the first df because you had no `else` statement to handle the case of `c` existing (i.e `FALSE` in the `if` statement).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `dplyr::bind_rows` to bind `data.frame`s in the `list` and fill entries from missing columns with `NA`, and then split the resulting `data.frame` again to produce a `list` of `data.frame`s:

```
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(l, .id = "id");
lapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) x[, -1])
#$`1`
#  a b c
#1 1 2 4
#2 2 3 5
#
#$`2`
#  a b  c
#3 1 2 NA
#4 2 3 NA
```

Or the same as a `tidyverse`/`magrittr` chain

```
bind_rows(l, .id = "id") %>% split(., .$id) %>% lapply(function(x) x[, -1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(purrr)

map(l, ~{if(!length(.x$c)) .x$c <- NA; .x})
```